# Java Source code not showing (IntelliJ?)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ and developing code using Java.

When I use "Go to Declaration" [Ctrl+B] to a Java inbuilt feature (e.g. ArrayList), it takes me to that class (e.g. ArrayList.class) and looks a bit like this:

```
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file  
// Implementation of methods is not available

package java.util;

public class ArrayList <E>  extends java.util.AbstractList<E>
implements java.util.List<E>, java.util.RandomAccess,
java.lang.Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8683452581122892189L;
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
private static final java.lang.Object[] EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
private transient java.lang.Object[] elementData;
private int size;
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 2147483639;

public ArrayList(int i) { /* compiled code */ }

public ArrayList() { /* compiled code */ }

public ArrayList(java.util.Collection<? extends E> es) { /* compiled code */ }
```

However I seen it on other computer and it actually shows the Java source, not just a comment saying "compiled code".

How do I get this on my computer. Have I set up Java incorrectly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to configure it in your project structure (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) settings here:

[image]

Is your JDK pointing to an invalid Sourcepath?

Comment: I don't seem to have that src.zip folder? How do I get it. Did I install wrong or do I need to install something additional? Currently there's nothing there for my sourcepath

Comment: @YahyaUddin what JDK are you using? OpenJDK? Another one? How did you install it?

Comment: I'm using the JDK on the Oracle offical site: jdk1.7.0_40. It's not OpenJDK.

Comment: I got it off a website like this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen

Comment: But of course it was version 7 not 8. Do i need to get it off a website like OpenJDK??? Is this not included in the standard edition.

Comment: @YahyaUddin are you sure you got the JDK and not the JRE?  I downloaded mine the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used the new JDK 8 and it included the src and it work fine. Many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and OpenJDK 8.
To get the JDK sources I had to separately install an additional package:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-source
```

Thanks to https://askubuntu.com/questions/755853/how-to-install-jdk-sources for the solution.

Comment: On arch linux it was 'yaourt -S openjdk8-src'

Comment: I also had to go back to IntelliJ and under Settings > Platform Settings > SDKs > select my Java version > Sourcepath add '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk'.